# gitlab-runner pipeline stop running randomly without explicit error

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

we had an issue with our gitlab-runner K8s executor .
Some pipelines of some of our projects stop running without explicit error.
I checked logs on gitlab side, gitlab runner side, pipeline syntax and k8s workers machines logs  but I found nothing useful.
The only error I see is in the gitlab-runner logs "forbiden error" which doesn't seem to be the real error :

```
Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=679800 job-log=0-1656 job-status=running runner=1AEgbfPE sent-log=1139-1655 status=202 Accepted update-interval=3s
Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=679800 job-log=0-2611 job-status=running runner=1AEgbfPE sent-log=1656-2610 status=202 Accepted update-interval=3s
WARNING: Appending trace to coordinator... job failed  code=403 job=679800 job-log= job-status= runner=1AEgbfPE sent-log=2611-13929 status=403 Forbidden update-interval=0s
Waiting for build to finish...                      error=canceled job=679800 project=1588 runner=1AEgbfPE
Skipping referees execution                         job=679800 project=1588 runner=1AEgbfPE
WARNING: Error while executing file based variables removal script  error=context canceled job=679800 project=1588 runner=1AEgbfPE
                      duration_s=15.557665444 job=679800 project=1588 runner=1AEgbfPE
WARNING: Appending trace to coordinator... job failed  code=403 job=679800 job-log= job-status= runner=1AEgbfPE sent-log=2611-14009 status=403 Forbidden update-interval=0s
Submitting job to coordinator... ok                 code=200 job=679800 job-status= runner=1AEgbfPE update-interval=0s
```

An example : with some helm chart deployment project , it stop running when i add "--debug" and it  run completely when i remove this option .

I am able for some project to run the pipeline but after many retries , for others it is never succeed .
do you know how can i do more debbug on that or maybe is it a bug?
How can i find more logs for the helper and build container after it die ?

The version of the chart Helm is: `0.46.2`
Gitlab version : GitLab Community Edition `14.2.7`

Update :
i think that the issue is that the job is getting canceled as the logs show
`Waiting for build to finish...error=canceled job=679800 project=1588` 
But i do not know who is canceling the job because it was not canced from the UI .

Comment: This is a problem with your runner setup. `WARNING: Appending trace to coordinator... job failed  code=403 job=679800 job-log= job-status= runner=1AEgbfPE sent-log=2611-13929 status=403 Forbidden update-interval=0s` Your runner is trying to update gitlab (the coordinator) with the job trace (logs) but is getting an access denied result.